# Facebook extending user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

Facebook documentation says `offline_access` is depreca ted.How do I extend the access token for 60 day?

I did enabled deprecated `offline_access` from advanced settings for app.

Comment: @DMCS: I did it in the same way $facebook->api('/oauth/access_token', 'GET', 
array('client_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'client_secret' => 
  FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET, 'grant_type' => 'fb_exchange_token',  
  'fb_exchange_token' => $token)); i get out as NULL in var_dump()

Comment: good question, i assume all accesstokens will 60 days long after deprication. And if the user engages within this time, it will be extended automatically. so you have to log user's actions to check it is expired or not.

Comment: @Tolga Arican:It is expiring after 2 hour's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extend access token validity since offline_access deprecation](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8982025/how-to-extend-access-token-validity-since-offline-access-deprecation)

Comment: try this link http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10132610/how-to-handle-facebooks-deprecation-of-offline-access-when-you-use-token-both-i

Answer (score 0):

you can try to two ways:
1. enable the offline deprecation functionality, and grab the exchanged token value in available and then run cUrl functionality. After running the cUrl just pass the response value in var_dump().. you could see the access token and the expires date..

1. you will get different value for the opposite process of (1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/ for long lived access tokens, or https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/ for non-expiring app access tokens.  But you probably need the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function fb_renew_access_token($args=array()){
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".$args["app_id"]."&client_secret=".$args["app_secret"]."&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=".$args["old_token"];

     $c = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
     $contents = curl_exec($c);
     $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);

    $paramsfb = null;
    parse_str($contents, $paramsfb);

    return $paramsfb;
 }
 //to get the extended access token
 $extended_access = fb_renew_access_token(array("app_id"=>"4545454544s45454545","app_secret"=>"sdfgds2fg4d2f54g5df4gdsdsfgdsfg54dfg","old_token"=>"54sdf54sd54f35asdgs4ghdsd5sh4d5trh4djhdfj45fdh"));
```